# AVPlayer add movie to view

Tags: ios, avplayer

Assuming the code below, how would I display the mov within the movieView please?  Do I need to subclass AVPlayer in this way or is there a more straightforward way of achieving this?

```
UIView *movieView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 1080)];
movieView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:movieView];

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"Clock_stroke_04_Full" withExtension:@"mov"];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[self.playerView setMovieToPlayer:self.player];
[self.player play];
```

---

```
    @implementation AVPlayerClass

    + (Class)layerClass
    {
        return [AVPlayerLayer class];
    }

- (AVPlayer*)player
    {
        return [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] player];
    }

    -(void)setMovieToPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player
    {
        [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
    }
```

---

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayer *player;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayerClass *playerView;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AVAsset *demoAsset =[AVAsset assetWithURL:self.videoUrl];
AVPlayerItem *tAVPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:demoAsset];
AVPlayer* demoAVPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:tAVPlayerItem];
AVPlayerLayer *demoAVPlayerLayer=[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:demoAVPlayer];
demoAVPlayerLayer.frame = self.videoCollageView.frame;
demoAVPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.videoCollageView.layer addSublayer:demoAVPlayerLayer];
[demoAVPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[demoAVPlayer play];
```

please try to run this code.Thanks